# How do I change class value Python 3?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use OOP to make tic tac toe, but whenever I win/draw a game is just keeps running and won't cancel out the game?

The error seems to be something to do with my while loop not wanted to break out.
Maybe this is a really stupid and obvious error in my code, but I've only been learning Python for 3 months so unfortunately I'm not the best right now.

```
# The
```

Comment: `while player1.has_won == True and player2.has_won == True:` will loop the game while... _both_ players have won. How can both win? Either one wins or there's a draw, so nobody wins.

Comment: Adding to what @ForceBru said, you need to check the outcome of the move after each move by the players ```
        player1.move()
        if player1.has_won:
            break ``` 
        Then do the same after player2.move()

Comment: @ForceBru What would i chnage this too iam bit confused.

Comment: @Mj_, you should use `or` instead of `and`, if you want to loop until _either_ of them have won.

Comment: @ForceBru I chnaged the pvp while loop to or ,and it just cancels the game at the start, hope you can help

Comment: @RobPy can you show me what you mean by this?

Comment: @Mj_ oh wait, that was completely wrong, sorry. On the contrary, you should loop _while_ none of them have won, so `while not (player1.has_won or player2.has_won)`. By De Morgan's laws, this is equivalent to `(not player1.has_won) and (not player2.has_won)`.

Comment: @ForceBru Oh thanks alot,however it doesnt end the game until the next play types any input?

Answer (score 1):

In the *p_v_p()* function it checks while both players have won, could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Iam confused on what i would change this too? have i done some logic wrong.

Comment: you need to make sure player one OR player two has completed the game as once one player has completed the game needs to end. your code will only finish once both players win because you use an and

Comment: if i chnage the pvp loop to or it just cancels the game right away? hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the class variable isn't changed, it's that you're not checking it frequently enough. FYI, you called it a class variable in your question, but has_won is actually an instance variable. There are two problems that need to be corrected.

Your diagonal win conditions are incorrect:

> `diagnol_win = [[1,4,9],[3,4,7]]`

This should be `diagnol_win = [[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]`

As @rob-py mentioned, you need to check has_won after each move. The following should fix the issue.

```
def p_v_p():
    print("\nWelcome to Player vs Player Game Mode\
          Player 1 you are 'X' , Player 2 you are 'O'!")
    while True:
        print("\nPlayer Ones Turn!")
        player1.move()
        if player1.has_won:
            return
        print("\nPlayer Twos Turn!")
        player2.move()
        if player2.has_won:
            return
```

Since you're new to python, I thought I could offer some suggestions. I think you're off to a good start, but I would suggest defining three main classes: Player, Board, and Game. Here's a (at least mostly) working example. Keep in mind that this was a quick edit, so there's still plenty of room for more improvement.

```py
class Board():
    class PositionError(RuntimeError):
        pass

    class UpdateError(RuntimeError):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.markers = [' '] * 9

    def print(self):
        print()
        print(self.markers[:3])
        print(self.markers[3:6])
        print(self.markers[6:])

    def update(self, position, marker):
        if position < 1 or position > 9:
            raise self.PositionError()
        if self.markers[position - 1] != ' ':
            raise self.UpdateError()
        self.markers[position - 1] = marker

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.markers[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.update(index + 1, value)

class Player:
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.has_won = False
        self.counter = counter
        
    def move(self, board):
        while True:
            try:
                player_input = int(input("Where you you like to place your counter? (1-9): "))
                board.update(player_input, self.counter)
                return
            except ValueError:
                print("\nInvalid Input not an number,Try Again.")
                continue
            except Board.PositionError:
                print("\nPlease enter a position between 1-9")
                continue
            except Board.UpdateError:
                print("\nPosition {} is already taken".format(player_input))
                continue

class Computer(Player):
    def move(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
        
class Game:
    DRAW = 'D'
    INCOMPLETE = 'I'
    HORIZONTAL_WIN = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    VERTICAL_WIN = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
    DIAGONAL_WIN = [[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
        
    def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
        self.player_1 = player_1
        self.player_2 = player_2
        self.board = Board()

    def reset(self):
        self.board = Board()

    def play(self):
        index = 0
        players = [self.player_1, self.player_2]
        while True:
            players[index].move(self.board)
            self.board.print()
            state = self.check_state()
            if state == players[index].counter:
                print("\nPlayer with counter {} has won!".format(players[index].counter))
                break
            if state == self.DRAW:
                print("\nTHIS GAME IS A DRAW! NOBODY WINS!")
                break
            index =  (index + 1) % len(players)
        self.reset()
        return

    def check_state(self):
        if len([c for c in self.board.markers if c in ['O', 'X']]) >= 9:
            return self.DRAW
        
        for x, y, z in self.HORIZONTAL_WIN:
            if self.board[x-1] == self.board[y-1] == self.board[z-1] != " ":
                return self.board[x-1]
        for x, y, z in self.VERTICAL_WIN:
            if self.board[x-1] == self.board[y-1] == self.board[z-1] != " ":
                return self.board[x-1]
        for x, y, z in self.DIAGONAL_WIN:
            if self.board[x-1] == self.board[y-1] == self.board[z-1] != " ":
                return self.board[x-1]

        return self.INCOMPLETE

def p_v_p():
    print("\nWelcome to Player vs Player Game Mode")
    print("Player 1 you are 'X' , Player 2 you are 'O'!")
    return Game(Player('X'), Player('O'))

def p_v_c():
    print("\nWelcome to Player vs Computer")
    print("Human player you are Player 1 and counter 'X'. "
          "The Computer is player 2 and counter 'O'")
    
    return Game(Player('X'), Computer('0'))
        

def game_selection():
        while True:
            game_mode = input("""\nEnter what game mode you want to play:
- Player Vs Player (PvP)
- Player vs Computer (PvC)
Type your desired game mode here: """)
            if game_mode.lower() == 'pvp':
                return p_v_p()    # Calls function for Player vs Player
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        game_selection().play()
        if not input('Play again? [y/N]: ').lower().startswith('y'):
            break
```

Comment: Is there a way to be able to reset objects so i can let the user play the game again?

Comment: The game resets itself upon completion. I updated the suggested code to offer a choice to play again. See the main code at the bottom.